# Unsubscribe observable's promise

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

How do I unsubscribe an observable if it's converted to promise?
I'm using RxJS in Angular 2

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                  .toPromise()
                  .then(this.extractData)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you **subscribe** to an **Observable** then it is possible to **unsubscribe** to it.
 When you return **promise**(here it seems you return promise -*not* **observable**), *you usually don't subscribe to it*. right?? 
So you can't unsubscribe to it(promise).

Comment: How about unsubscribing of a `Observable.fromPromise()` ?

Comment: @Abdel : The unsubscribe is automatic. If you check the source code of Observable.fromPromise() , the onCompleted() function is called  in the observer.https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/frompromise.js

Comment: @MaximeLeprince Would that mean promises can technically be cancelled as well?

Comment: @Abdel : No because when you call subscribe, the promise is triggered. Next if you unsubscribe from the observable, you could not have the result but the promise will be neverthelesse computed